# spin.js is not showing up on my site?

Tags: javascript, spin.js

I am new to Javacript (very, very new) and I need to place a loading spinner on a site. We currently have a screensaver and once you tap the screen it takes a awhile to get to the necessary url. So, we wanted to place a spinner to make sure users would not continue to tap the screen.

I am using spin.js abd I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong as it is not showing up when I do a test.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<title>THE TITLE</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #000;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width: 1024px;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}
a,img,map,area {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="spin.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
var opts = {
  lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
  length: 20, // The length of each line
  width: 10, // The line thickness
  radius: 30, // The radius of the inner circle
  corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
  rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
  direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
  color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
  speed: 1, // Rounds per second
  trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
  shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
  hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
  className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
  zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
  top: '50%', // Top position relative to parent
  left: '50%' // Left position relative to parent
};
var target = document.getElementById('foo');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts).spin(target);
    </script>
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="timeout(7,goto,'screen3.html');">
<a href="SITE URL"><img src="screen2.jpg" width="1024" height="768" border="0"></a>
    <div id="spinner">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things are wrong with your code:

- you have 2 closing `<script/>` tags after eachother (right before ), so that's a syntax error.
- you have another syntax error. You're not closing jqueries `document.ready` function properly.
- You're using a jQuery method but you're not including the jQuery library in your code.
- You say `color:'#000'` in the spinner options, which means the spinner will be black (same as your background color so you will never see it).

The spinner works in its most simple form. See working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/wLkganhm/

If you're very new to javascript I suggest reading up on how to use the debugger so you can find the syntax errors for yourself :)

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely find the issues and see if that will fix it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Consider upvoting or accepting the answer if it was of any help.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your code as already pointed out. 
I've put up a cleaned up version here http://jsbin.com/payuzeyopa.

Things to improve on/fix:

1. Try using a site like JSFiddle or JSBin to share/prototype your code with others
2. Keep your HTML, CSS and JavaScript files separate
3. Spot errors early by using tools built into the browser. For example, see http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/ for an excellent starter.
4. Finally, read up on JavaScript and HTML :)

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! I am always trying to learn more. :)